# Unity c# make player move as a projectile after colliding with other gameObjects

Tags: c#

When shooting a bullet or making a bomb explode, the player doesn't move as a projectile. Instead, they just move an unusually little distance. The players move as expected - a projectile, after reassigning groundCheck to "none", but the players themselves can't be moved any more. When colliding with a bullet or is in the range of a bomb, how can I change the code so that the player can move as a projectile without assigning groundCheck to "none" ?

Code of player:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class MoveWASDPlayer1 : MonoBehaviour
{
public float speed = 5;
public float jumpForce = 10;
private float moveInput;

private Rigidbody2D rb;

private bool facingRight = true;

private bool isGrounded;
public Transform groundCheck;
public float checkRadius = 0.5f;
public LayerMask whatIsGround;

private int extraJumps;
public int extraJumpsValue = 1;

public Sprite Player1Shoot;
public Sprite Player1idle;
public GameObject Player2;

public GameObject PistolBulletToRight, PistolBulletToLeft;
Vector2 PistolBulletPos;
public float fireRate;

public int remainingBullet = 10;

private void Start()
{
    extraJumps = extraJumpsValue;
    rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
}

void Update()
{
    Physics2D.IgnoreLayerCollision(6, 7);
    Shoot();
    CheckJumps();
    Flip();
    StartCoroutine(Fire());

    moveInput = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal1");
    rb.velocity = new Vector2(moveInput * speed, rb.velocity.y);

    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.S))
    {
        Physics2D.IgnoreLayerCollision(3, 6, true);
        Invoke("StopCollidingIntoGround", 0.25f);
    }
}

void CheckJumps()
{
    isGrounded = Physics2D.OverlapCircle(groundCheck.position, checkRadius, whatIsGround);

    if (isGrounded == true)
    {
        extraJumps = extraJumpsValue; ;
    }

    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.W) && extraJumps > 0)
    {
        rb.AddForce(Vector2.up * jumpForce, ForceMode2D.Impulse);
        extraJumps--;
        Physics2D.IgnoreLayerCollision(3, 6, true);
        Invoke("StopCollidingIntoGround", 0.48f);
    }
    else if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.W) && extraJumps == 0 && isGrounded == true)
    {
        rb.AddForce(Vector2.up * jumpForce, ForceMode2D.Impulse);
    }
}

void Flip()
{
    if (facingRight == false && moveInput > 0)
    {
        facingRight = !facingRight;
        Vector3 Scaler = transform.localScale;
        Scaler.x *= -1;
        transform.localScale = Scaler;
    }
    else if (facingRight == true && moveInput < 0)
    {
        facingRight = !facingRight;
        Vector3 Scaler = transform.localScale;
        Scaler.x *= -1;
        transform.localScale = Scaler;
    }   
}

void StopCollidingIntoGround()
{
    Physics2D.IgnoreLayerCollision(3, 6, false);
}

void Shoot()
{
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Z))
    {
        this.gameObject.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite = Player1Shoot;
    }
    if (Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.Z))
    {
        this.gameObject.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite = Player1idle;
    }
}

IEnumerator Fire()
{
    PistolBulletPos = transform.position;
    if (remainingBullet < 1)
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(2);
        remainingBullet = 10;
    }

    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Z) && remainingBullet > 0)
    {
        if (facingRight)
        {
            PistolBulletPos += new Vector2(+1f, -0.1f);
            Instantiate(PistolBulletToRight, PistolBulletPos, Quaternion.identity);
            remainingBullet--;
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(fireRate);
        }
        else
        {
            PistolBulletPos += new Vector2(-1f, -0.1f);
            Instantiate(PistolBulletToLeft, PistolBulletPos, Quaternion.identity);
            remainingBullet--;
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(fireRate);
        }
    }
}
}
```

Code of bomb:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Bomb : MonoBehaviour
{
Collider2D[] inExplosionRadius = null;
[SerializeField] private float ExplosionForceMulti = 5;
[SerializeField] private float ExplosionRadius = 5;

private void Update()
{
    if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.X))
    {
        Explode();
    }
}

void Explode()
{
    inExplosionRadius = Physics2D.OverlapCircleAll(transform.position, ExplosionRadius);

    foreach(Collider2D o in inExplosionRadius)
    {
        Rigidbody2D o_rigidbody = o.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        if (o_rigidbody != null)
        {
            Vector2 distanceVector = o.transform.position - transform.position;
            if(distanceVector.magnitude > 0)
            {
                float explosionForce = ExplosionForceMulti / distanceVector.magnitude;
                o_rigidbody.AddForce(distanceVector.normalized * explosionForce);
            }
        }
    }
}

private void OnDrawGizmos()
{
    Gizmos.DrawWireSphere(transform.position, ExplosionRadius);
}
}
```

Code of bullet:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PistolBullet : MonoBehaviour
{
public float velX = 5f;
float velY = 0f;
Rigidbody2D rb;

Collider2D[] inShootRadius = null;
[SerializeField] public float ShootForceMulti = 5;
[SerializeField] public float ShootRadius = 5;

private void Start()
{
    rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
}

private void Update()
{
    rb.velocity = new Vector2(velX, velY);
    Destroy(gameObject, 3f);
    Shoot();
}

public void Shoot()
{
    inShootRadius = Physics2D.OverlapCircleAll(transform.position, ShootRadius);

    foreach (Collider2D o in inShootRadius)
    {
        Rigidbody2D o_rigidbody = o.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        if (o_rigidbody != null)
        {
            Vector2 distanceVector = o.transform.position - transform.position;
            if (distanceVector.magnitude > 0)
            {
                float explosionForce = ShootForceMulti / distanceVector.magnitude;
                o_rigidbody.AddForce(distanceVector.normalized * explosionForce);
            }
        }
    }
}

private void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
{
    Destroy(gameObject);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly: When getting hit by a bullet or explosion the player is not flung as expected?

I would argue this is the culprit: `rb.velocity = new Vector2(moveInput * speed, rb.velocity.y);` as you are overriding the player velocity every frame without taking in account the current velocity, unless moveInput has that calculated into.

As to why it works when GroundCheck is unassigned, because the script stops executing due to the missing reference beforehand and the Rigidbody will only be modified from the other scripts.

Comment: How would you change rb.velocity if moveInput didn't have that calculated into?

Comment: I would keep the current velocity in mind and only apply changes on it, so something like `rb.velocity = rb.velocity + calculatedChange`. That way it isnt entirely overridden and only influenced. You already almost do this for the y component since you just take the component so your line could be `rb.velocity = new Vector2(rb.velocity.x + (moveInput * speed), rb.velocity.y);`. This way you would only influence the x axis obviously.